# How to make a navbar neatly open and close with javascript?

Tags: javascript, navigation, navbar, user-experience

I'd like to make a good navbar with the following functionality, but I can't seem to figure it out in javascript.

I'd like it to have the following functionality:

- Menu opens when a hamburger icon is clicked
- Menu closes when the hamburger icon is clicked again
- Menu is also closed if a link in the menu is clicked
- Menu is also closed if anywhere outside of the menu is clicked

I've already added a (.active for my css menu class which can toggle whether or not the menu is displayed.) Now I originally did an onclick function, but while not only was it not good practice, it also did not give the UX I would like. This is because the only way the menu would appear or disappear was if the hamburger menu was pressed.

Here's some basic html and css that follows similarly to what I am working with:

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L0vr8j59/

(Note: the hamburger icon only appears at screen width 800px or less via a media query)

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar">
        <div class="nav-list">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#link2">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#link3">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#link4">Link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="hamburger" class="hamburgermenu">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

li{
    font-size: 2.75rem;
}

li a:hover{
    text-decoration: overline;
}

.hamburgermenu{
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.hamburgermenu span{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 4px;
    width: 40px;
    margin: 4px;
    background: black;
}

ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: black;
}

.navbar{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    filter: blur(5px);
    z-index: -10;
    color: white;
}

.navbar.active{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    z-index: 20;
}

.navbar.active::before{
    box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar.active ul a {
    color: white;
}

.navbar.active .hamburgermenu span{
    background-color: white;
}

.nav-list{
    display: block;
    padding-left: 50%;
    line-height: 5rem;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

@media  screen and (max-width: 800px) {

    .nav-list{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }

    #menu{
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    #menu.active{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        top: 5px;
        background-color: rgb(61, 60, 60);
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 5ms ease-in;
    }

    ul a{
        color: white;
    }

    .hamburgermenu{
        display: flex;
        visibility: visible;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
        margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
        align-items: flex-end;
        padding-right: 2rem;
    }
```

I can also provide any additional info if needed.

Thanks in advance. :D

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on how to write posts that most enable the community to provide helpful assistance.  This question is rather short on details and is rather broad-- rather than being a specific programming problem, it is a list of requirements of what you want.  Your post will get more positive attention if you show what you have tried and where specifically in your code you are facing issues.  I'd recommend updating with a [mvce].  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Is there anything more I can add to make this more straightforward?

Comment: Sorry, I typed it incorrectly.  I recommend including a [mcve] as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do), and clearly explain the problem you are having, the expected output, the actual output, and how they differ.

Comment: I made a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/L0vr8j59/

(Note: the hamburger icon only appears at screen width 800px or less via a media query.)

I would like to use javascript (and likely eventlistners) to add the following functionality: 

-Clicking the hamburger icon will open the menu of links
-Clicking the hamburger icon if the menu is visible will close it (making it invisible.)
-Clicking a link will also close the visible menu
-Clicking anywhere other than the visible menu will also close the visible menu.